# Android app memory heap keeps growing

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I've been getting random ( out of memory ) crashes in my app so I started to analyze my heap. I noticed that if I go from Activity A to Activity B, the heap increases ( due to lazy loading many images ) from 27 MB to 35 MB. However, when I finish() the activity B to return to Activity A, the heap size keeps the same even with GC operation !!

The annoying thing is that going to activity B one more time again increases the heap to 42 MB. I can do this as may times and the heap will only keep increasing.

This is the lazy images loading library I am using:

LazyList https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

These are screenshots of the Heap

before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eTzm.png

after: https://i.stack.imgur.com/txeC6.png

converted heap dump file is available upon request

**UPDATE**

From my debugging, it seems the issue from the LazyList library but I am still not 100% sure. Here is reference to people commenting on the library :

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/issues/20

Comment: Sounds like your activity is leaking some data. Do you have any IPC member variables, or anything else that can continue on without an activity?

Comment: No IPC's 
For continuing without activity, the library I am using uses multiple threads ( which car run without activity ).

Comment: have you resolve this issue then please feedback is expected..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're leaking the activity (which would probably leak all variables it holds).  Make sure that any OS call that required you to pass a context have been unregistered, that you don't have any objects that hold a reference to the activity (especially via holding around a context) and that you null out everything you can in onDestroy or onStop (and do so in all your major objects as well).

If that isn't enough, look at your hprof and see what large objects are lieing around after you kill the activity and who's holding the references.  Fix and repeat.

Comment: How do you I un-register OS call that requires to pass context ? 
Could you show me an example ?

Comment: Where are you using the context? If it's inside a listener you might need to get rid of it. But in general, I don't think there's a need for you too keep a reference from Activity A to Activity B, like, ever.

Comment: I agree with that.  But its not uncommon to pass Context objects to listeners or data objects who store them as member variables, and if you don't null those out you will leak.  Its even not uncommon to then later decide to make those variables singletons or globals, not thinking of that context variable lieing around (heck, it may even have been passed into some other object's constructor who does that but you just have the original object lieing around).  Common reasons for doing this is access to things like SharedPreferences or XXXManager classes.

Comment: @dmon how do I get rid of the context inside the listener ?

Comment: @GabeSechan but why would any listener in Activity A have a reference to Activity B? 
AlAsiri: you can't. You'd have to stop referencing the listener.

Comment: It doesn't.  But if the framework doesn't have every instance unregistered, it will keep the activity object in memory (because there's a live reference, thus the GC won't delete it) which causes it to leak.  It has nothing to do with cross activity handles.  Although those can occur too if you decide to make a singleton or Application variable. that has a Context reference in it.

Comment: Found it, it was bunch of objects that I allocated and system didn't release them when I exited the activity. thus, I had to release them manually by deleting them . 
Thanks for the help guys !!

Comment: Read a bit about WeakReference at:

[WeakReference by Aritra Roy](https://techbeacon.com/app-dev-testing/what-you-need-know-about-android-app-memory-leaks) 

[WeakReference by Said Tahsin Dane](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/weakreference-in-android-dd1e66b9be9d)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you are starting a new activity each time, rather than switching to the one already loaded. Try setting the flags on the intent to include **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT** when you switch activities.

[See this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

Comment: I think this is not the issue as the already open activity should be  clean by GC, the reason is due to memory leaked where the activity reference is hold by some reference and the activity instance is unable to clean..

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me it could be the images you're using. The [BitmapFactory from Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) creates immutable Bitmaps and any changes you make to those Bitmaps will therefore be separate from the original image.

Worse yet, even if you tell it to [recycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29), it will depend on your references if it will be garbage-collected.

Comment: I think so too 
You think  a SoftRefrence would solve this issue ?

Comment: I'd be more inclined to use the advice offered here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html. This here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html seems particularly relevant.